# how to make a check for update option in python

Tags: python-3.x, auto-update

I have a remote operations tool made in python and I have distributed it to my friend and he is using it good.
Now, whenever I add a feature to my app i would have to text him the link of my app (manual update type thing) which is bugging for a while.
So is there anyway I could add a auto-update feature a.k.a. check for update to my application for a automated update???
I googled about this but I couldn't find anything related and so I am stuck

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called esky in which if you freeze with it, it can check for updates on a certain website, get a list of avaliable versions on a certain website, distribute patch files, and much more. check out here: [esky](https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky) p.s. I dont know if there is a version for 3.x though.